# Bash script doesn't appear to work from Cron

Tags: bash, shell, cron, mogrify

I created a bash script to run mogrify via cron. Can anyone see why the below script content might not optimize the jpeg images? Of course this works when manually doing things within shell.

The output seems to work, so I know there are no errors. Any assistance would be helpful.

```
#!/bin/bash
clear
cd /home/urc3s/public_html/public/uploads/
mogrify -resize "1000x1000>" *.jpg
cd /home/urc3s/public_html/public/uploads/
mogrify -resize "1000x1000>" *.JPG
echo "All done."
```

Comment: Put `exec >/tmp/cron.log 2>&1; set -x` on the line below your shebang, and [edit] the content of `/tmp/cron.log` into your question. (BTW, `clear` doesn't make sense in the context of a `cron` job; you don't need to `cd` to the same place more than once; but you *should* check for whether your `cd` fails and exit if it did).

Comment: ...so, `cd /somewhere || exit` will exit with a nonzero status (indicating failure) if the `cd` operation failed. Similarly, because you have an `echo` as your last line, the exit of your script itself is currently that of the `echo` command, *not* the exit status of `mogrify`, so `cron` can't see that mogrify failed in order to send an email (assuming you have local mail delivery correctly configured in the first place, of course).

Comment: BTW, the [`cron` tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/cron/info) is a good place to start -- make sure you've read through the common mistakes it discusses.